# Inherit all styles from base theme expect a few

Tags: 7, theming

I am doing a base theme and child theme. I want the child theme to inherit all the css from the base theme expect a few for which i will have the stylesheet in this child theme. How will i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted on the [sub-theme page](http://drupal.org/node/225125), a sub (or child) theme will inherit all the parent's css files "as long as you declare at least one stylesheet in your sub-theme's .info file".

You can override a stylesheet simply by declaring one of the same name in your sub-theme's .info file. If there is a stylesheet you don't want in your sub-theme, just add an empty file with same name to the sub-theme's .info file.

Comment: That does't seem to be the case, or at least not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the template.php file

```
 <?php
 global $theme;
 if($theme=='parent_theme_name'){
   drupal_add_css('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Trocchi', array('type' => 'external', 'group' => CSS_THEME));
 }
```